# Is there something like stateful continuations or continuations with saved heap?

Tags: functional-programming, heap-memory, continuations

In functional programming, continuations are very useful because continuations store the program counter and stack; mutable heap is not necessary to save obviously.

What about if you want to apply continuations in non-functional programming languages like Java, JavaScript, etc? Here, we should save the mutable heap to correctly resume a program if you need. I was looking for a technique like continuations that we can use in this kind of language (e.g. Java), but I could n't find it. Do you know something about this?

Comment: Continuations don't store "program counter", "stack" or "heap". They store sufficient state that allows them to *continue* (hence the name *"continuation"*) from where they left off. A *closure* in Java, etc, "closes over" mutable and immutable data that is needed for it to run. As such, it knows nothing about heaps or stacks.

Comment: What do you mean by "*mutable heap is not necessary*"? Also why do you consider JavaScript non-functional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think typical continuation implementations support the automatic tracking of the heap, but it is definitely something that can be added relatively easily.

For example, the [Seaside web framework](https://github.com/SeasideSt/Seaside) uses continuations to model the flow of displayed components. Since saving the complete heap would be expensive, developers can [register which objects they like to track](https://github.com/SeasideSt/Seaside/wiki/Maintaining-State#backtracking). This works by creating a snapshot at the time the continuation is created, and restoring the object at the time the continuation is resumed. This enables to automatically restore application state as the back- and forward buttons in the browser are used.